# After insert, transform and insert into another table

Tags: python, postgresql, events, flask, sqlalchemy

I have two tables `Document` and `Picture`. The relationship is that one document can have several pictures. What should happen is that once a document is uploaded to the `PostgreSQL`, the document should be downloaded and transformed into a jpeg, and then uploaded to the `Picture` table.

I'm using `sqlalchemy` and `flask` in my application.
So far I tried using `events` to trigger a method after insert. Unfortunately, I am receiving the error `sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This transaction is closed` when I commit.

The code:

```
from app.models.ex_model import Document, Picture
from pdf2image import convert_from_bytes
from sqlalchemy import event
import io
import ipdb

from app.core.app_setup import db
@event.listens_for(Document, 'after_insert')
def receive_after_insert(mapper, connection, target):
    document = target.document

    images = convert_from_bytes(document, fmt='jpeg')
    images_bytes = map(lambda img: convert_to_byte(img), images)
    map(lambda img_byte: upload_picture(img_byte, target.id, ), images_bytes)

    db.session.commit()


def convert_img_to_byte(img):
    img_byte = io.BytesIO()
    img.save(img_byte, format='jpeg')
    img_byte = img_byte.getvalue()
    return img_byte

def upload_picture(img_byte, document_id):
    picture = Picture(picture=img_byte, document_id=document_id)
    db.session.add(picture)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [`Session.add`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.add) method states:

> Its state will be persisted to the database on the next `flush`
>   operation.
> Repeated calls to `add()` will be ignored.

So your `add` calls should be followed by `session.flush()` call.

```
...
def upload_picture(img_byte, document_id):
    picture = Picture(picture=img_byte, document_id=document_id)
    db.session.add(picture)
    db.session.flush()
```

Furthermore I would pay attention to performance of inserting records. There's a good article for this point in official docs: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/faq/performance.html#i-m-inserting-400-000-rows-with-the-orm-and-it-s-really-slow

As such the current approach is not the fastest one, therefore I would choose either `sqlalchemy_orm_bulk_insert` or `sqlalchemy_core` approach.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The error when committing is still there unfortunatly·

Comment: @CarlRynegardh, check if your `db.session` is initialized properly (google search: *session sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError*)

Comment: I'm having no problem with uploading to the database. It's just in this method.